# Drawing graph based on match function

Tags: php, graph

I'm looking for php class to draw graph direct from match function, e.g.:

"f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c" as parameter

and get graph like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function

Maby you know some opensource class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for. It is an open-source graph rendering utility for PHP.